# Skype for business with HAProxy as reverse proxy

Tags: haproxy

Good day, everyone! I have a problem with HAProxy and Skype for Business. I need to set up my reverse-proxy to work with S4B Edge. I’m new in HAProxy, so I have a few questions. Can anyone tell me which config i should use for port and how to use certificate for incoming connections to the Edge-Server. Will appriciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a listener that presents a certificate for the relevant Skype for Business CNAMEs for your domain (see the S4B documentation). This may be the same certificate you use on your actual Edge server too. Then create rules that send requests for all these names to the Edge server.

Very naïve config example to illustrate:

```
frontend s4b
    bind "${virtualip}":443 name s4b_tls ssl crt sip_yourdomain_com.pem # Contains all relevant hostnames as Subject Alternative Names
    use_backend bk_s4b if { hdr(Host) -i meet.yourdomain.com }
    use_backend bk_s4b if { hdr(Host) -i lyncdiscover.yourdomain.com }
    use_backend bk_s4b if { hdr(Host) -i dialin.yourdomain.com }
    use_backend bk_s4b if { hdr(Host) -i lsweb.yourdomain.com }

backend bk_s4b
    server s4bedge edgeserver.yourdomain.com:4443 check ssl ca-file your-ca-root-cert.pem # Which you get from your CA if it isn't included in the OS
```

Comment: Thank You, I'll try to use this rule!

Comment: As I wrote, this is a naïve config. It may work as a proof of concept but probably shouldn't be copy-pasted straight into production without some additional hardening and checks. Do yourself a favor and read up a bit more on HAProxy before making your systems dependent on it, so you don't shoot yourself in the foot. :)

Comment: I did as you said. Made some changes to config, but still having the same error...

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: ssl handshake faillure

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more information than that. First of all, do all of the required services work from within your network when connecting directly to the Edge server? If you perform a manual `curl -v` from a shell session, does the TLS handshake make sense? If so, your Edge server is probably correctly configured. The next step would be to point the DNS names in question at the HAProxy listener address in your local hosts-file and see if it looks more or less similar...

Comment: ... It's also a good idea to read the HAProxy logs to try to ascertain whether the failure you see happens between the client and HAProxy or between HAProxy and the Edge server.